# C#: How do you manage symbolic constants in your projects? Where do you declare solution scope constants?

Tags: c#, constants

How do you manage symbolic constants in your projects?  Where do you declare solution scope constants ?

Comment: Never use public constants, they are replaced by literals in the IL.  Use public readonly variables.

Comment: @Hans: very good point, thank you but could you please tell me that how can I see this by myself?

Comment: You could look at the generated IL with ildasm.exe

Answer (score 4):

We have a constants class where we put all the constants in.   We declare it static and then make the constants static public, since there is no need to instantiate it.

Comment: yeah, I should have put that in too.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty rare (for me at least) that there isn't an obvious relationship between such constants and some pre-existing class at the heart of the domain model - I'd just add them there. Then the constants are tightly scoped to the appropriate part of the model, rather than just being in a "Constants" class.

Of course, I also find it pretty rare to find true "constants"; many interesting "constants" are described better through configuration options.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts.  Constants, if I have them, are typically only meaningful -- or at least most meaningfully used within a class. Globally used values are almost always configuration items, i.e., they're constant once set, but are best defined in a configuration file.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I've also found on more than one occasion that even my "global options" soon become injection options, with different use-cases using different global options. Multi-tenancy being the most obvious example.

Comment: I assume that these are cached in some global dictionary or do you retrieve them from persistence medium each time?